# Why we use interface as main concept in Java?

Tags: java, interface

Can you please provide me best use of interface, because further complete reading I have not found anything which proves why we use interface.

I have read everything about interface but could not found solution to that why interface is used. Please explain me with examples.

Comment: @Tech4Way Why it's different?

Comment: You haven't? Stop looking for best use of interface, start looking for worst use of inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The principle of an interface is simple: it is a *contract*.

An interface is documented; the methods of an interface do one thing and do it well, and it is up to implementations to ensure that the contract is fulfilled.

For instance, let us take a simple interface, `Iterator`. You have `Collections.emptyIterator()` which fulfills this interface. For whatever class X, you can declare:

```
final Iterator<X> iterator = Collections.emptyIterator();
```

You are guaranteed that this particular implementation will correctly implement the `next()`, `.hasNext()` and `.remove()` methods.

Similarly, if you have a `List<X>` and you do:

```
final Iterator<X> iterator = list.iterator();
```

you are guaranteed the same.

Accessing through interfaces allow you to tell users that this is the contract they should use for this particular method of yours. The implementation *does not matter*, and that is the key here.